# Bring your own encryption - Postgresql 10 - Multi-tenant db

Tags: postgresql, encryption, postgresql-10

New to Stack so forgive me if I'm doing something incorrectly here...

We are currently working in postgressql 10, servicing multiple customers,  setup using centralized tables partitioned by a customer id.  The setup is AWS/EC2, with the traditional ETL approach of each client file going into their own table in an import schema (import.clientA_members) before being standardized and going to prod.members with clientA used as a partition.

Recently, a few clients have brought "Bring your own key" requirements and I am struggling with the best approach to implement this. The setup seems pretty straightforward if we had a database per client but as it stands right now that would cause some pretty big shifts on how we approach everything here from scalability and efficiency to reporting and analytics.

Has anyone here run into this situation?  I'm not a DBA, more of an operator, so I'm not sure what the options are in terms of encrypting partitions with different keys, and those keys working well with the AWS Key Management Store.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe the desired behavior of "bring your own key" in more detail? I have not heard that term before.

Comment: I'll do my best :) . Basically it's a setup where the customer provides us with their key so that they can revoke access to their data in our system at any time.  Usually includes a middle piece of technology with shared control for the customer to upload and us to access the key.  https://www.thalesesecurity.com/faq/key-secrets-management/what-bring-your-own-key-byok